# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/Screens/Login/components/background.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/components/have_an_acc.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/components/own_button.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/components/own_input_field.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/components/own_password_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/screens/homepage/home_page.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/screens/signup/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:ourchat/services/auth.dart';
import '../../../helper/helper_functions.dart';
import '../../../services/database.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  TextEditingController emailEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  AuthMethods authService = new AuthMethods();
  bool isLoading = false;
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  signIn() async {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      await authService
          .signInWithEmailandPassword(
              emailEditingController.text, passwordEditingController.text)
          .then((result) async {
        if (result != null) {
          QuerySnapshot userInfoSnapshot =
              await DatabaseMethods().getUserInfo(emailEditingController.text);

          HelperFunctions.saveUserLoggedInSharedPreference(true);
          HelperFunctions.saveUserNameSharedPreference(
              userInfoSnapshot.docs[0].data("userName")); //=> error
          HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(
              userInfoSnapshot.docs[0].data["userEmail"]); //=> error

          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        } else {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
            //show snackbar
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'.
> Try defining the operator '[]'.
> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
> Try removing the extra arguments.

**Friends, using Firebase, I try to log in with e-mail and password, but this method does not work and I get such an error. Does anyone know the solution?**

Answer (score 0):

Because firebase provider’s info is a Map<String, dynamic>, the values data[‘userName’] & data[‘userEmail’] are not “String”!
To solve this, you can write

```
HelperFunctions.saveUserNameSharedPreference(
          userInfoSnapshot.docs[0].data("userName") as String); //=> error
HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(
          userInfoSnapshot.docs[0].data["userEmail"] as String); //=> error
```

but, this might cause a bug, if the **userName** or **userEmail** is null,

So a better solution is,

```
final userName = userInfoSnapshot.docs[0].data("userName") as String?;
final userEmail = userInfoSnapshot.docs[0].data("userEmail") as String?;

if(userName?.isNotEmpty ?? false)
  HelperFunctions.saveUserNameSharedPreference(userName); //=> error

if(userEmail?.isNotEmpty ?? false)
  HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(userEmail);
```

Comment: not working idk..